# replace weighted linearlayout in scroll view with constrainLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

how to replace weighted linearLayout in scroll view
 with constrainLayout chains i looked and tried chains but they stick the view by the end of the screen and the chain make equal size parts in the screen and put the views in it but what i want is to make vertical views that have the same height based in the biggest view of them and let them go beyond screen height

Comment: Can you post your XML, what you've tried till now?
And also if possible the screenshot or design of what you want to achieve, so that everybody here can help you with exactly what you need

Comment: @ParagPawar what i want is how to do it so any idea would help